# Average delay to get a badge after completing the requirements

Tags: support, badges, notifications

What is the average delay between the time that all of the conditions for the badge have been met and the user actually receiving the badge?

Comment: Assuming uniform distribution of badge earning: `(Time between script runs) / 2`

Comment: @Mysticial ...and, the time of the script runs can be found by analyzing the `Badges.CreationDate` distribution on the SEDE :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That depends on the job calculating the badge. It might be seconds, minutes or hours.

Jobs that take a lot of performance run not as often as others. And sites that are not so heavily visited deliver badges faster.